# Postfix logs missing information on delivery status (postfix/smtp message)

Tags: postfix, logging, freebsd, syslog

I noticed a problem with postfix logs, that information on some of emails delivery status is missing. The issue affects about 1% of emails.

"Healthy" log:

```
<server># grep 8EB992EFBB44 postfix_log/mail04.log
Jun  5 03:09:29 mail04 postfix/smtpd[8537]: 8EB992EFBB44: client=xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jun  5 03:09:29 mail04 postfix/cleanup[34349]: 8EB992EFBB44: message-id=<20120605010929.123.456@xxx.xxx.xxx>
Jun  5 03:12:02 mail04 postfix/qmgr[76377]: 8EB992EFBB44: from=<xxx@xxx.xxx>, size=48845, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  5 03:15:12 mail04 postfix/smtp[35058]: 8EB992EFBB44: to=<foo@baz.com>, relay=mx.baz.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, conn_use=70, delay=343, delays=153/190/0/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok)
Jun  5 03:15:12 mail04 postfix/qmgr[76377]: 8EB992EFBB44: removed
```

"Broken" log:

```
<server># grep F3C362EF37CA postfix_log/mail04.log
Jun  5 04:03:27 mail04 postfix/smtpd[39666]: F3C362EF37CA: client=xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jun  5 04:03:27 mail04 postfix/cleanup[41287]: F3C362EF37CA: message-id=<20120605020327.449.100@xxx.xxx.xxx>
Jun  5 04:03:28 mail04 postfix/qmgr[76377]: F3C362EF37CA: from=<xxx@xxx.xxx>, size=48892, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
** here should be a log line from postfix/smtp but there is none **
Jun  5 04:03:29 mail04 postfix/qmgr[76377]: F3C362EF37CA: removed
```

Background information:

system: `FreeBSD xxx.xxx.xxx 8.2-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE #0: Thu Feb 17 02:41:51 UTC 2011     root@mason.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64`

Postfix is installed inside jail. Logs are on the same machine, log dir is mounted thru nullfs. The site has spikes of heavy load, causing disks (local) to run at 100%.

**Update**

The log is rotated daily, current size is ~ 500MB.

I made a test by queuing 99000 messages to same destination (in order to rule out dns/network/mx issues). 5715 messages don't have any DSN record. Failed messages queue time is spread evenly over time, i don't see any time-bound issues.

Some undelivered emails:

```
  envelopeid  |       processed_time
--------------+----------------------------
 8D7652EF3BAE | 2012-06-06 13:19:11.072715
 DD53A2EF3C5C | 2012-06-06 13:33:24.374783
 8C52F2EF4E3F | 2012-06-06 13:39:15.810616
 BBC572EF525C | 2012-06-06 13:44:22.762812
 E95822EF54D1 | 2012-06-06 13:52:01.134533
 839DD2EF4FBB | 2012-06-06 14:13:48.511236
 017EE2EF6234 | 2012-06-06 15:04:48.618963
```

Those are a few picks, such records of undelivered email occur almost every second.

```
<server># egrep '(8D7652EF3BAE|BBC572EF525C|017EE2EF6234)' mail04.log
Jun  6 13:19:10 mail04 postfix/smtpd[20350]: 8D7652EF3BAE: client=xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jun  6 13:19:10 mail04 postfix/cleanup[21024]: 8D7652EF3BAE: message-id=<20120606111910.674@xxx.xxx.xxx>
Jun  6 13:19:10 mail04 postfix/qmgr[7939]: 8D7652EF3BAE: from=<xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx>, size=63718, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  6 13:19:11 mail04 postfix/qmgr[7939]: 8D7652EF3BAE: removed
Jun  6 13:44:22 mail04 postfix/smtpd[20346]: BBC572EF525C: client=xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jun  6 13:44:22 mail04 postfix/cleanup[24811]: BBC572EF525C: message-id=<20120606114422.674@xxx.xxx.xxx>
Jun  6 13:44:22 mail04 postfix/qmgr[7939]: BBC572EF525C: from=<xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx>, size=63758, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun  6 15:04:49 mail04 postfix/smtpd[20344]: 017EE2EF6234: client=xxx.xxx.xxx[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
Jun  6 15:04:49 mail04 postfix/cleanup[35585]: 017EE2EF6234: message-id=<20120606130448.674@xxx.xxx.xxx>
Jun  6 15:04:49 mail04 postfix/qmgr[7939]: 017EE2EF6234: from=<xxx@xxx.xxx.xxx>, size=63706, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
<server>#
<server># find /var/spool/postfix/active/ -type f -print | wc -l
       1
<server>#
```

IMPORTANT: As you can see above some of emails doesn't event have the `removed` line.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is related to the queue manager (qmgr). This might be caused by really heavy traffic. Are you monitoring the postmaster account? I would suggest that you 1) put a -v on the qmgr in the master.conf to get it to spit a few more lines. 2) change the notify_classes in main.cf to include bounce, delay, resource, software and see if that catches any problems. You could also use the qshape tool to examine the queues in case there is a real congestion. It looks that those messages above are out-going, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhIch postfix version is this ?

Have you tried tuning syslog ?
If the disk is at or near its I/O capacity, syslogs may be delayed longer than you expect.

Also, what is "mail04.log" ? How big is it ? Are you certain the entirety of that message was logged in that file ?

Send the logs offsite using either UDP or (better) TCP remote syslog and check that the message is missing from all logs.

Comment: You were right, the issue was syslog related. The problem is, that the disks were so overloaded, that syslog wasn't able to keep up with writing logs. As a result (as I see it) packets were dropped form the syslog datagram unix socket. 

I was able to fix this issue by moving logs to another physical drive.

Answer (score 0):

If any Postfix processes are configured in `$config_directory/master.cf` to run in the chroot jail, you need to configure syslogd to listen on `$queue_directory/dev/log` in addition to the default `/dev/log` socket (so that chrooted processes will have access to `/dev/log` inside chroot). If you don't do this, initially things seem to work, but logging from chrooted processes breaks when syslogd is restarted for some reason (which may happen during log rotation).

Comment: If I understand tha correctly, you suggest that log is truncated or so. That is not the case, undelivered mail is spread evenly thruout time. There are some lost messages almost every second.